# programmatically moving the mouse while the computer is locked

Tags: windows, winapi, mouse

I have a program which monitors user's presence by monitoring the mouse movements. I need to make that program think that a user is present at all times. Programmatically moving the mouse every once in a while is very simple. However, I can't make this work when the computer is locked.

I work on Windows XP and have no need for the solution to support Vista or 7.

Comment: Do you mean 'programmatically' (twice)?

Comment: [SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208.aspx) might help you achieve what you want in a different way.

Comment: Seems the program literally monitors mouse movements and not the idle timer, so I don't think SetThreadExecutionState will work.

Comment: Do you know what method the program is using to monitor mouse movements? Polling, or looking for WM_MOUSEMOVE, or...?

Comment: I don't know, why does it matter?

Comment: If you're trying to fool the *program*, then you can always just send it fake `WM_INPUT` messages, and then hope for the best...

Comment: It's a service, doesn't have a window...

Comment: @Vadim I'm not sure how a service would go about monitor mouse movement. What is this service?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Simulating a mouse click instead worked for me... just get your screen position and keep tapping it.

```
private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, uint dwExtraInf);

// tap on a timer somewhere inside the app region
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: mouse_event is the legacy API that is superseded by SendInput.

Comment: Any why the P/Invoke? I can't see any reference to .net. There are still some of us left who write native code in Windows.